# Perl reset variable

Tags: perl, shell, scripting

I'm learning Perl, and I made a script that will use defined variables in the beginning of my script to establish connection,pull records, modify them, then close connection.

the second part of my work involve repeating the same steps but for different server.

is there is a way to un-set whatever variables has been set before? and then use new defined settings and repeat the steps?

Thank you

Comment: You should consider the type of variable that you refers, is it an array? or a hash? or a scalar?. Generally I reset this with `@array = ();` or `%hash = ();`

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a subroutine (a.k.a. function) with parameters.

Comment: I usually just declare types at the beginning and assign as I go. Just reassign them but a function with parameters would be better.

Comment: @bwtrent, can I assume you come from a C background?

Comment: Reusing variables is horrible practice. Then you have to scan backwards in the code to see where they have been changed. Declare variables with a limited scope, and don't repeat your code: make a subroutine instead.

Comment: @JoelBerger you are correct. I mainly use perl for quick and dirty file manipulation.

Comment: @bwtrent, for a one-off you might be ok, but for anything larger, tight scoping of variables is a really Good Thing (TM) in Perl. Give it a try next time, and even if not, please don't teach the newbies not to :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your variables in their own scope.

```
{
    my $server = '123.123.123.123';
    my $username = 'user1';
    ping($server);
    login($username);
}
{
    my $server = '222.222.123.123';
    my $username = 'user2';
    ping($server);
    login($username);
}
```

Even better, use a function definition:

```
sub doSomethingToServer
{
    my ($server, $username) = @_;
    ping($server);
    login($username);
}

doSomethingToServer('123.123.123.123', 'user1');
doSomethingToServer('222.222.123.123', 'user2');
```